# Формат округления в финансовых расчетах

Tags: java

В финансовых расчетах результат надо представить в виде суммы, округленной до копеек. Использую этот метод:

```
public double round(double value, int precision) {
    return new BigDecimal(value).setScale(precision, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).doubleValue();
}
```

Проблема в том, что большие суммы представляются в таком виде:
1.0328923E7

Как победить?

Answer (score 2):

Вы приводите ваш `BigDecimal` к `double`, наверное метод должен выглядеть вот так

```
public static BigDecimal round(double value, int precision) {
    return new BigDecimal(value).setScale(precision, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
}
```